# Comparing with integer value in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I want to write an sql query where if the sum of particular column is zero, then the result will be retrieved. I have tried as below:( I have only written the checking part as the error is coming for this part only).

```
query=.... WHERE SUM(column1)='0'
```

coumn1 has integer datatype. I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid use of group function
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is wrong . You should use `having` clause if you want to work with aggregate functions like `sum()`.

> The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

Look at the [MySql documentation of SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> The WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that rows must satisfy to be selected. where_condition is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be selected. The statement selects all rows if there is no WHERE clause.
>
> **In the WHERE expression, you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (summary) functions.**

Comment: thanks, worked for me, for functions like SUM(), instead of WHERE clause HAVING should be used. Below is the working query
query=...HAVING SUM(column1) =0

Answer (score 1):

The **HAVING** clause is used in the SELECT statement to specify filter conditions for group of rows or aggregates.

The MySQL HAVING clause is often used with the GROUP BY clause. When using with the GROUP BY clause, you can apply a filter condition to the columns that appear in the GROUP BY clause. If the GROUP BY clause is omitted, the MySQL HAVING clause behaves like the WHERE clause. Notice that the MySQL HAVING clause applies the condition to each group of rows, while the WHERE clause applies the condition to each individual row.

Use `HAVING` in your query with aggregate functions :

```
query=.... HAVING SUM(column1)='0';
```